# Using while loop to repeat a function that generates random numbers

Tags: python, loops, random, while-loop, append

I am having trouble when using a `while` loop to repeat a function.

I am not an American student so please be understanding of my English.
I have no clue of what is going wrong and hope I can get some help.
I am aware that I can append the random number in the function and return it.

The question is:

There is a dice with 5 sides and each side says a , b , c , d ,e. If I get a d or an e, I throw again and I log this until I get an a,b or a c. ex) if I throw the dice 5times I can get: d, e, d, d, a or something like this. In my program, I want to simulate this process. I want it so that the function randomnumbers can generate random numbers from 0~4. I want the main program to loop the process of getting random numbers via this function(mandatory). Then, I want the main program to retrieve these values and use it to determine what these numbers mean(0=a, 1=b, 2=c, 3=d, 4=e) on the dice and append them to a separate list. Finally I want to print the values in the list where I logged the values I got.

I specifically have to do the following:

> 1. The function should only return one random number, not a list
> 2. The main program should be responsible for making a list and printing the value retrieved from the function.

```
def randomnumbers():
    r = 0
    import random
    r = random.randrange(0,5)
    return r

abc = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

List = []
while randomnumbers()>=3:
    List.append(abc[randomnumbers()])

for i in List:
    print i
```

Comment: don't import random in your function

Comment: What's this `while randomnumbers()>=3:` supposed to be doing?

Comment: your function randomnumber **does** return only one value

Comment: As far as I can see, this code is correct. If it doesn't produce expected results, please define expected results.

Comment: You need to show us what the output of your program should look like. Is it just supposed to be a list of random numbers? Or is supposed to be a list of random letters from  the `abc` list. How many items should be in the list?

Comment: You are generating a new random number every time you call `randomnumbers()`. So when you check your random number with `while`, it will be a totally different number when you `append` it to your list.

Comment: The code is working, but if you expect it only to return 'd' and 'e' it fails because of your second call of randomnumbers() inside of the loop.

Comment: @Ptank Hi, thank you for your comment. In light of your suggestion I have imported the random in the main program. However, I am still having trouble with the results. Sometimes the program does not display anything. I think I have problems both in the function and the while loop. Can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Note that this code has a 60% chance of generating nothing, a 24% chance of one char, a 9.6% chance of two chars...

Comment: Hi, the expected result would be that the while loop would repeat while the value of the function is greater than 3. As a result the random numbers would be used to retrieve values in the abc list, and be appended to List. Finally the for loop would print all the values in List.

Comment: @ Hugh Bothwell, I would expect this program to generate at least one char, what would I have to do to achieve this?..

Comment: by the way, 0 = a, 1 = b, 2 = c, 3 = d, 4 = e

Comment: You really don't need a `randomnumbers` function for this task. You can just call `r = random.randrange(5)` in a `while` loop.

Comment: @PM2Ring yes, I am aware of this but it is mandatory that i generate random numbers between 0~4 through the function randomnumbers.

Comment: Let me describe the question again. There is a dice with 5 sides and each side says a , b , c , d ,e. If I get a d or an e, I throw again and I log this until I get an a,b or a c. ex) if I throw the dice 5times I can get: d, e, d, d, a or something like this. In my program, I want to simulate this process. I want it so that the function randomnumbers can generate random numbers from 0~4. I want the main program to loop the process of getting random numbers via this function(mandatory).

Comment: Then, I want the main program to retrieve these values and use it to determine what these numbers mean(0=a, 1=b, 2=c, 3=d, 4=e) on the dice and append them to a separate list. Finally I want to print the values in the list where I logged the values I got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling your function twice. Try to use:

```
import random
def randomnumbers():
    r = 0
    r = random.randrange(0,5)
    return r

abc = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

List = []
while True:
    rand_number = randomnumbers()
    List.append(abc[rand_number])
    if rand_number <3:
        break


for i in List:
    print (i)
```

Comment: I fixed this issue. Right.

Comment: I tried this but there are times when the program generates no value.

Comment: As Hugh wrote in the comments of your question, the chance for this is quiet high. This is the case when the first random number is below 3. Thats the logic of your while loop.

Comment: Hi, I would you mind taking a look at the comments again, I just described the question again. I apologise for the inconvenience..

Comment: Now it works as you described in the comments.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random                        
def randomnumbers():                 
    r = 0                            
    r = random.randrange(0,5)        
    return r                         

abc = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]      

List = []                            
while True:
    nb = randomnumbers()
    if nb >=3:
     List.append(abc[nb])
    elif not List:
        continue
    else:
        break

for i in List:                       
    print i
```

Comment: Hi, I am not trying to get the list to be more than 3 char but I am trying to stop the loop when the function generates a number greater or equal to 3

Comment: ok, but in this case, just add a condition to re run your function if List is empty

Comment: Hi, I would you mind taking a look at the comments again, I just described the question again. I apologise for the inconvenience..

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick!

```
from random import shuffle
abc = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
your_list=[]
your_list.extend(abc)
shuffle(your_list)
print(your_list)
```

output:

```
['e', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'b']
```

Well if you want a new list from an old list with elements changed in random order.

That is if you want abc = ['a','b','c'] to be shuffled into say ['c','a','b']
in a random manner then use **shuffle()**

Comment: What makes you think the OP wants to shuffle the list? Also, `your_list = abc` is pointless: that just binds the name `your_list` to the same list object as `abc`. See what happens if you put `print(abc)` at the end of your code. Were you expecting it to copy the list?

Comment: That's the most stupidest thing I've ever done. Silly careless mistake man. Thanks for pointing out. It's a bit embarassing. Also I didn't think OP would want this as a solution just wanted to mention a different way to get a solution which i happen to know. That's all. The other answers are ready for him to choose if he wants to!

Comment: Hi, I would you mind taking a look at the comments again, I just described the question again. I apologise for the inconvenience..

Comment: @Korean okay will check and give a solution wait.

Comment: It can be tricky posting answers before the OP has fully clarified the question. But you _can_ edit this answer so that it _does_ answer the actual question. :)

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, you really don't need a `randomnumbers` function for this task. You can just call `random.randrange` directly. But I guess this is a homework task, and it's mandatory for you to have a `randomnumbers` function, so I've simplified it.

You also say that you want the `while` loop to run while the random number is greater than or equal to 3, and that you expect the list to contain at least one letter. That means you need to test the value of the random number *after* you use it to select a letter from `abc` and add the letter to the list. You can do that like this:

```
import random

def randomnumbers():
    return random.randrange(5)

abc = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

lst = []
while True:
    r = randomnumbers()
    lst.append(abc[r])
    if r < 3:
        break

for i in lst:
    print(i)
```

---

This code runs correctly on both Python 2 and Python 3.

I changed the name of your output list to `lst`. According to the [PEP-0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide variable names should be all lower-case, names that are Capitalized or CamelCase are used for class names.

---

FWIW, here's a slightly more "Pythonic" way to write that loop:

```
lst = []
while True:
    lst.append(random.choice("abcde"))
    if lst[-1] < "d":
        break
```

Comment: Hi, I would you mind taking a look at the comments again, I just described the question again. I apologise for the inconvenience..

Comment: Thank you I have added the new info.

Comment: @Korean And I've updated my answer.

Comment: I've checked the code, but in some cases I still get a, b, or c as an answer. I think Franz did exactly what I needed. You should check out his answer. I really appreciate you trying to help me actively.

Comment: @Korean Of course you sometimes get a, b, or c as an answer. And when that happens, the loop stops. That's what you asked for. FWIW, my code and Franz's code are essentially identical.